# Replacing the spread operator?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function.

```
alias.writeDialogue = function() {
    return writeDialogue(...arguments);
};
```

I wish to support IE, which doesn't support the spread operator. With what should I replace `...`?

Comment: have you heard of [babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=IYGwlsDOB0DuBOYAuBTAIhEB7A5gVxQAIBeQgMzwDsBjJMLSgCgEpCBvAKEO8PhSTzxKhBMnSZcBRtBnB4-ALYpKSSMwDcHAL7qgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=env&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=1.6.2)

Comment: isn't it (almost) equivalent to `alias.writeDialogue = writeDialogue`?

Comment: @appleapple I've used that statement earlier on in the programme, so you'd've thought that I'd think to use it now, and that solution, in this case, is exactly what I needed. Thank you for pointing out my idiocy! EDIT: Ah - but will `alias.x = x` also return what x returns? EDIT: Yes it will.

Comment: I'm glad to help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `apply` to transform an array of arguments into an argument list:

```
return writeDialogue.apply(undefined, arguments);
```

But it would be better to integrate Babel into your build process, so that you can write with modern syntax and have it transpiled into ES5-compatible syntax automatically. For example

https://babeljs.io/repl/

Plug in

```
alias = {
  writeDialogue: function() {
    return writeDialogue(...arguments);
  }
}
```

and you get

```
"use strict";

alias = {
  writeDialogue: function (_writeDialogue) {
    function writeDialogue() {
      return _writeDialogue.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    writeDialogue.toString = function () {
      return _writeDialogue.toString();
    };

    return writeDialogue;
  }(function () {
    return writeDialogue.apply(undefined, arguments);
  })
};
```

Babel will also automatically transpile arrow functions, `const` and `let`, `async`/`await` (with RegeneratorRuntime), and so on. It's a must-have.